# Counting distinguishable groupings.

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have 6 distinguishable objects that you will group into three groups each of size 2.  Here is one way to count all possible groupings:

$$ \frac{\binom 6 2 \binom 4 2 \binom 2 2}{3!} $$

the idea being that you choose elements to go into each of the groups, and then divide out the over-counting by the number of ways to arrange the groups.

But it also seems like this could be counted as a multinomial:

$$ \frac{6!}{2!^3} $$

where the logic is that you could imagine the numbers laid out as

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

and then place letters for the three groups.  So the letters

A, A, B, B, C, C

would represent 1,2 in group A, and so on.

These answers seem not to come out to the same value, so clearly my logic is wrong on one of them, but I can't see a problem with either counting method.

Comment: Your groups are unlabeled in the first method but labeled in the second one.

Comment: ${\binom 6 2 \binom 4 2 \binom 2 2} = \frac{6!}{2!^3} $